# Adding subtotals to R data table as base for ggplot2 waterfall chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, waterfall

I am trying to make a waterfall chart in R using the ggplot2 package. As there is no default template for it (and I want to stick to the ggplot2 package), I have to prepare the data by myself.

I am following [this](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/ggplot2-waterfall-charts/) tutorial, but I want to include subtotals in my plot, so some rows in my dataset need to be summed up and the subtotal line should appears in the middle of the data frame

So I have a table like this:

```
Position     Value
       1        52
       2        12
       3       -14
       4       -25
       5       -10
       6        60
       7       -30
```

And I would like it to become like this:

```
Position     Value
       1        52
       2        12
   Subt1        64
       3       -14
       4       -25
       5       -10
   Subt2        15
       6        60
       7       -30
   Subt3        45
```

As there are not too many positions in my list, I can do the mapping (`Subt1 = 1 + 2; Subt2 = Subt1 + 3 + 4 + 5; ...`) manually once I know how it works. Still, I don't know how to enter the sums dynamically into my list. The ordering can be done manually afterwards, too.

Thank you guys!

Comment: how did you get `14 + 25 + 10 = 15`

Comment: The subtotals are part of the calculation: `64 - 14 - 25 - 10 = 15`

Answer (score 1):

An option is `group_split` based on a grouping vector created with `rleid` on the `sign` of the 'Value' column, then loop through the `list` of `data.frame` and `add_row` at the end with `sum` of 'Value'

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tibble)
library(data.table)
df1 %>%
    group_split(grp = rleid(sign(Value)), keep = FALSE) %>%
    map_df(~ .x %>% add_row(Position = 'Subt1', Value = sum(.$Value)))
```